# superimposed nodes & connection labels in TikZ decision tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels, tikz-trees

I'm trying to build a decision tree using the `TikZ` package and have run into an issue. Two of my nodes from separate branches are superimposed, so I can only see one of the nodes and on the surface the two separate branches are conflated. The code allows me only to manipulate node distance through a global parameter that affects the distance between all nodes at once. Is there a way to manipulate only a subset of nodes and separate the overlapping nodes, without changing the distance between all the nodes?

This is my code and output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=15em,
every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=gray!20}]]
\node {no slopes}
child { node {subj slope} 
    child { node {subj \& item slopes} 
        child { node {\textbf{max RE}} }
        child { node {\textbf{subj slope}} }} %this node is buried and not visible
    child { node {item slope} 
        child { node {subj \& item slopes} 
            child { node {\textbf{max RE}} } 
            child { node {\textbf{item slope}} } } 
        child { node {\textbf{no slopes}} } }};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With pure TikZ is less elegant as with `forest` ... but with appropriate determined `sibling distance` for the first and the third level you can obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  level 1/.style = {sibling distance=17em},
  level 3/.style = {sibling distance=8em},
every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                     draw, align=center,
                     top color=white, bottom color=gray!20}
                     ]
\node {no slopes}
    child { node {subj slope}
        child { node {subj \& item slopes}
            child { node {\textbf{max RE}} }
            child { node {\textbf{subj slope}} }
               } %this node is buried and not visible
        child { node {item slope}
            child { node {subj \& item slopes}
                child { node {\textbf{max RE}} }
                child { node {\textbf{item slope}} } 
                   }
            child { node {\textbf{no slopes}} } 
                }
            };
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for working within TikZ! It is a little easier to modify existing code that you use a different package, even if it's less elegant.

Answer (score 4):

A `forest` version of your tree, where `s sep` define the minimum distance between nodes boundaries, and `l sep` the minimal distance between node and its descendants. to increase them just add `+` sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={l sep+=.8cm,s sep+=.5cm,shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=gray!20}
[no slopes
  [subject slope
     [subj \& item slopes,for children={font=\bfseries} 
       [max RE]
       [subj slope]     
     ]
     [max RE,font=\bfseries  
       [subj \& item slopes,for children={font=\bfseries}
         [max RE]
         [item slope]       
       ]
       [no slopes]
     ]
   ]  
]    
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to the forest package. It seems easier to use that TikZ.